# More memory efficient way of making a dictionary?

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

VERY sorry for the vagueness, but I don't actually know what part of what I'm doing is inefficient.

I've made a program that takes a list of positive integers (example*):

```
[1, 1, 3, 5, 16, 2, 4, 6, 6, 8, 9, 24, 200,]
```

*the real lists can be up to 2000 in length and the elements between 0 and 100,000 exclusive

And creates a dictionary where each number tupled with its index (like so: `(number, index)`) is a key and the value for each key is a list of every number (and that number's index) in the input that it goes evenly into.

So the entry for the 3 would be: `(3, 2): [(16, 4), (6, 7), (6, 8), (9, 10), (24, 11)]`

My code is this:

```
num_dict = {}
sorted_list = sorted(beginning_list)

for a2, a in enumerate(sorted_list):
    num_dict[(a, a2)] = []

for x2, x in enumerate(sorted_list):
    for y2, y in enumerate(sorted_list[x2 + 1:]):
        if y % x == 0:
            pair = (y, y2 + x2 + 1)
            num_dict[(x, x2)].append(pair)
```

But, when I run this script, I hit a `MemoryError`.

I understand that this means that I am running out of memory but in the situation I'm in, adding more ram or updating to a 64-bit version of python is not an option.

I am certain that the problem is not coming from the list sorting or the first for loop. It has to be the second for loop. I just included the other lines for context.

The full output for the list above would be (sorry for the unsortedness, that's just how dictionaries do):

```
(200, 12): []
(6, 7): [(24, 11)]
(16, 10): []
(6, 6): [(6, 7), (24, 11)]
(5, 5): [(200, 12)]
(4, 4): [(8, 8), (16, 10), (24, 11), (200, 12)]
(9, 9): []
(8, 8): [(16, 10), (24, 11), (200, 12)]
(2, 2): [(4, 4), (6, 6), (6, 7), (8, 8), (16, 10), (24, 11), (200, 12)]
(24, 11): []
(1, 0): [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (6, 7), (8, 8), (9, 9), (16, 10), (24, 11), (200, 12)]
(1, 1): [(2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (6, 7), (8, 8), (9, 9), (16, 10), (24, 11), (200, 12)]
(3, 3): [(6, 6), (6, 7), (9, 9), (24, 11)]
```

Is there a better way of going about this?

#### EDIT:

This dictionary will then be fed into this:

```
ans_set = set()
for x in num_dict:
    for y in num_dict[x]:
        for z in num_dict[y]:
            ans_set.add((x[0], y[0], z[0]))
return len(ans_set)
```

to find all unique possible triplets in which the 3rd value can be evenly divided by the 2nd value which can be evenly divided by the 1st.

If you think you know of a better way of doing the entire thing, I'm open to redoing the whole of it.

## Final Edit

I've found the best way to find the number of triples by reevaluating what I needed it to do. This method doesn't actually find the triples, it just counts them.

```
def foo(l):
    llen = len(l)
    total = 0
    cache = {}
    for i in range(llen):
        cache[i] = 0
    for x in range(llen):
        for y in range(x + 1, llen):
            if l[y] % l[x] == 0:
                cache[y] += 1
                total += cache[x]
    return total
```

And here's a version of the function that explains the thought process as it goes (not good for huge lists though because of spam prints):

```
def bar(l):
    list_length = len(l)
    total_triples = 0
    cache = {}
    for i in range(list_length):
        cache[i] = 0
    for x in range(list_length):
        print("\n\nfor index[{}]: {}".format(x, l[x]))
        for y in range(x + 1, list_length):
            print("\n\ttry index[{}]: {}".format(y, l[y]))
            if l[y] % l[x] == 0:
                print("\n\t\t{} can be evenly diveded by {}".format(l[y], l[x]))
                cache[y] += 1
                total_triples += cache[x]
                print("\t\tcache[{0}] is now {1}".format(y, cache[y]))
                print("\t\tcount is now {}".format(total_triples))
                print("\t\t(+{} from cache[{}])".format(cache[x], x))
            else:
                print("\n\t\tfalse")
    print("\ntotal number of triples:", total_triples)
```

Comment: This, for now, sounds like a XY problem. Why do you need this data and how you plan to use it? Without knowing this it's hard to suggest better alternatives.

Comment: Given the style of the solution, I would guess this is a programming problem that performs some kind of range-based query on arbitrary sections of the dataset.  These types of problems are generally solvable using dynamic programming principles, not building giant maps of possible answers.

Comment: Not sure if that will help much but you could at least divide your memory requirement by 2 by using only indices since knowing the index gives you the value.

Comment: I've made an edit

Comment: Given your edit, I think you need to rethink your algorithm, if you run into memory issues creating your dictionary, looping over it with depth 3 will certainly take forever... + you will also face even bigger memory issues in your next step with `ans_set`! Dynamic programming as suggested by paddy is probably a thing to look into.

Comment: In the worst case you will have 4,000,000 integer items plus 2000 x 2 integer keys plus the structure overhead. That would use only a few megabytes of memory. Do you have a traceback?

Comment: I feel like I'm missing out on something... is there more to 'dynamic programming' than just optimizing my code? How would i go about implementing it (I just looked at the Wikipedia page for dynamic programming and am still confused).

Comment: @KlausD. well, I'm sorry to say I don't have a traceback. This is part of my solution to a Google FooBar challenge (I know, cringey me looking up the answers to a "fun challenge" [at least I try first]) and the console there doesn't provide feedback at all other than line numbers / error names.

Comment: Cross-reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937160/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-find-factors-in-a-list ?

Comment: @גלעדברקן yeah, that was a previous question I had on the same problem

Comment: But didn't those answers already enable you to write a fast program?

Comment: Yes, I don't have the issue with it taking too long, it now takes too much ram

Comment: So the `1` at the start of the list -- two of them -- would be a complete duplicate of every member of the list since `1` is an even divisor of everything, correct?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could *start* by not unnecessarily duplicating information.

Storing full tuples (number and index) for each multiple is inefficient when you already have that information available.

For example, rather than:

```
(3, 2): [(16, 4), (6, 7), (6, 8), (9, 10), (24, 11)]
```

(the `16` appears to be wrong there as it's *not* a multiple of `3` so I'm guessing you meant `15`) you could instead opt for:

```
(3, 2): [15, 6, 9, 24]
(6, 7): ...
```

That pretty much halves your storage needs since you can go from the `6` in the list and find all its indexes by searching the tuples. That will, of course, be extra *processing* effort to traverse the list but it's probably better to have a slower working solution than a faster non-working one :-)

---

You could reduce the storage even more by not storing the multiples at all, instead running through the tuple list using `%` to see if you have a multiple.

---

But, of course, this all depends on your *actual* requirements which would be better off stating the *intent* of what your trying to achieve rather than pre-supposing a solution.

Comment: oops, yeah, the 16 was a mistake. If you look at my edit you might be able to see why I need the values to also have their indexes with them (the values need to refer directly back to other keys)

Comment: I've made an edit elaborating on what I need the dictionary for. If I have the `%` within my other code, I think it becomes an O(N^3) problem

Answer (score 2):

You rebuild tuples in places like `pair = (y, y2 + x2 + 1)` and `num_dict[(x, x2)].append(pair)` when you could build a canonical set of tuples early on and then just put references in the containers. I cobbled up a 2000 item test my machine that works. I have python 3.4 64 bit with a relatively modest 3.5 GIG of RAM...

```
import random

# a test list that should generate longish lists
l = list(random.randint(0, 2000) for _ in range(2000))

# setup canonical index and sort ascending
sorted_index = sorted((v,i) for i,v in enumerate(l))

num_dict = {}
for idx, vi in enumerate(sorted_index):
    v = vi[0]
    num_dict[vi] = [vi2 for vi2 in sorted_index[idx+1:] if not vi2[0] % v]

for item in num_dict.items():
    print(item)
```

Comment: This will do a nice job of conserving memory by making a single instance of each tuple.